# parsing text file in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, text-parsing

i am trying to parse a text file saved in doc dir below show is the code for it

```
NSArray *filePaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *docDirPath=[filePaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath=[docDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SKU.txt"];
NSError *error;
NSString *fileContents=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSLog(@"fileContents---%@",fileContents);   
if(!fileContents)
NSLog(@"error in reading file----%@",error);
NSArray *values=[fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSLog(@"values-----%@",values);

NSMutableArray *parsedValues=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int i=0;i<[values count];i++){
    NSString *lineStr=[values objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"linestr---%@",lineStr);
    NSMutableDictionary *valuesDic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    NSArray *seperatedValues=[[NSArray alloc]init];
    seperatedValues=[lineStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSLog(@"seperatedvalues---%@",seperatedValues);
    [valuesDic setObject:seperatedValues forKey:[seperatedValues objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSLog(@"valuesDic---%@",valuesDic);
    [parsedValues addObject:valuesDic];
    [seperatedValues release];
    [valuesDic release];
}
NSLog(@"parsedValues----%@",parsedValues);
NSMutableDictionary *result;
result=[parsedValues objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"res----%@",[result objectForKey:@"WALM-FT"]);
```

The problem what i am facing is when i try to print lineStr ie the data of the text file it is printing as a single string so i could not able to get the contents in line by line way please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Note that `stringWithContentsOfFile:` is deprecated.  It gives you no control over the encoding.  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringWithContentsOfFile_

Comment: If you're parsing a CSV file, you may want to consider using code that's [already been written to do that](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead use:

```
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)separator
```

it covers several different newline characters.

Example:

```
NSArray *values = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
for (NSString *lineStr in values) {
    // Parsing code here
}
```

ALso `seperatedValues` is over released.  First one is created with alloc init, then on the next line it is replaced by the method `componentsSeparatedByString`.  So the first one od lost without being released, that is a leak.  Later the `seperatedValues` created by `componentsSeparatedByString` is released but it is already auto released by `componentsSeparatedByString` to that is an over release;

Solve all the retain/release/autorelease problem with ARC (Automatic Reference Counting).

Here is a version that uses convenience methods and omits over release:

```
NSArray *values = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
for (NSString *lineStr in values) {
    NSArray *seperatedValues = [lineStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSString *key = [seperatedValues objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDictionary *valuesDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:seperatedValues forKey:key];
    [parsedValues addObject:valuesDic];
}
NSLog(@"parsedValues---%@",parsedValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the line separator used in your text file is `\n` and not `\r` (or `\r\n`)?

The problem may come from this, explaining why you don't manage to split the files into different lines.